# Can no longer SSH to VM as before from GCP dashboard, WordPress site down

Tags: ssh, wordpress, login, timeout

Edit: I have a 10GB VM. I’m thinking I’m out of space. Does this make sense?

I have been working on a WordPress (deployed using GCP onto Debian 9 OS) site for the past week, after setting up an external static IP, and all was fine till this morning.

Last things I did last night were to edit some text (which updated to site just fine) and to upload a dozen images (each 2 MB in size) via wp-admin for use in a post, just before bed.

Woke up this morning with an upload error--not all files uploaded. Also, I could not save any subsequent changes from wp-admin. I could no longer access the site from my browser, or my phone. The browser either completely hangs or I get a server stopped responding error.

I can ping the website's IP with success even as we speak.

I logged in to GCP and restarted my VM, but that didn't fix anything.

More than that, I cannot SSH in as before. After many many minutes, I get this error:

"VM guest environment outdated
The VM guest environment is outdated and only supports the deprecated 'sshKeys' metadata item. Please follow the steps here to update."

Not sure why I am guest now.

Launching phpmyadmin and wp-admin from the browser all spectacularly fail with "waiting for..." and then a server (408) timeout.

Bear with me, I am new to GCP and WordPress hosting, but I can't imagine how editing a post can cause this rather catastrophic turn of events. Something weird happened elsewhere. I have not been monkeying around with any settings via SSH, or even using GCP console prior to this event.

Please help!

Note: I am using the Free GCP plan at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It was probably out of disk. VM had 10GB.

From GCP console, I resized to 70GB, and that seemed to do the trick.

Managed to SSH in and ran a df -h command and the larger capacity had been automagically picked up.

I just did a VM restart and it’s all working again.

Comment: It's great that you got it working yourself, but you really should be posting the answer from the same account that you posted the question. See [help merging accounts](https://serverfault.com/help/merging-accounts).